# progress bar during loading

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview

i wrote an app with different views, the main one is basically a web view that displays a PDF on the web (with a specific url). the problem is that this pdf is a bit big (around 5-10 MB) and it takes a lot to load it. during this loading period the screen remains white. i thought to add a sort of progress bar that appears and disappers automatically, based on the file loading, but i have no idea about how to do this… can someone help me?

(if you have better ideas you are free to tell)

Comment: Head over to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol reference on developer.apple.com. Read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using web view to load the pdf then you can use the webview delegate methods to show the progress bar